# What is a VRAM?

Tags: graphics-card

I have PES 2012 installed on my HP (compaq) presario CQ61 notebook, but each time I try to open it it will give me a Warning :Your computer does not meet the Minimum System Requirements to run this software.As a result, you may experience errors during operation.Your Video Card does not meet the required specifications.(GPU:VRAM 128MB)

What could be the problem?

Comment: From what I can see on the HP website, this Laptop only has one graphics processor/card. Is that correct?

Comment: *What* software? What exactly is saying that, Windows? the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

VRAM stands for Video RAM.
So as warning says - Your graphic card have less than 128 MB of RAM therefore you can't play this game. There is no other solution than changing your laptop to new one (Almost always graphic cards are embedded in laptops which makes them impossible to upgrade.